# RAD 8.5 unable to run standalone java app that calls EJB and MQ

Tags: ejb, jndi, rad

I used to be able to run my standalone java app that calls EJB and MQ using JNDI on RAD 7.5.5. I upgraded to RAD 8.5 and when I tried to run it, I received the error `Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable`. I'm also using the same WAS 7.0.0.9 for both RAD version so I'm not sure why it's not working now.

Is there anything special that I need to do in RAD 8.5?
This is my bootstrap classpath entries: `WAS v7.0 JRE`, `%WAS_RUNTIME%\com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar`, `WAS v7.0 lib`.

Below are the lines where I set up the environment (the second line seems to be needed for RAD 8.5):

```
System.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809");
System.setProperty("com.ibm.ws.naming.wsn.factory.initial", "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
```

Below is the stack trace from my code:

```
2012-11-30 16:50:14,945 main FATAL ram.hs.edi.EDIDaemon(line 183) - Unable to get running status: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable. Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:243)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.initializeDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:327)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:357)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.internalInit(InitialContext.java:295)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:212)
at ram.hs.edi.utils.MQReader.open(MQReader.java:85)
at ram.hs.edi.EDIDaemon.isRunning(EDIDaemon.java:406)
at ram.hs.edi.EDIDaemon.run(EDIDaemon.java:168)
at ram.hs.edi.EDIDaemon.main(EDIDaemon.java:898)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers$2.run(CommonHelpers.java:268)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers$2.run(CommonHelpers.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.mergeJndiProviderProperties(CommonHelpers.java:263)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.mergeWsnJndiProperties(CommonHelpers.java:159)
at com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WsnInitialContextFactory.java:186)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:235)
... 8 more
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be little late answering it but please try to do the following:
1) Add the jar "com.ibm.ws.orb_7.0.0.jar" or equivalent jar on the Bootstrap path of your standalone Java Class.
2) Add the jar "com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_7.0.0" or equivalent jar on the JVM Class path.

After doing the above I was able to get the InitalContext successfully. Hope this helps.